# Getting facebook pictures with graph api using android studio

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, android-studio, photos

I cant figure out how to receive the users facebook albums and photos with graph api. I was able to get some info (with some help) like username, email etc. but can't figure out photos.

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                       String email = object.getString("email");
                        String nName = object.getString("name");
                        String nGender =object.getString("gender");
                        String uID = object.getString("id");






                        System.out.println("Info: " + email + nName + " " + nGender + uID );

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,photos");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a duplicate of [How to get Facebook profile image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310878/how-to-get-facebook-profile-image-in-android)

There is FB API reference for gathering data of album. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album/photos